# How to correctly install my released python package?

Tags: linux, installation, python, package-management

I released my package [reclib](https://pypi.org/project/reclib/) on PyPI

But when I try to `pip install reclib`, it gives me error:

```
WARNING: No metadata found in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytz-2019.2.dist-info/METADATA'
```

I release the package by the following steps:

I have registered the package on PyPI and modified the version in `setup.py`

1. `python setup.py sdist`
2. `twine upload --skip-existing dist/*`

What should I do to correctly release and install my python package?